# How to Enable Abode flash player at beginning for selenium latest version(Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Tags: selenium

While Executing Selenium Script by using chrome webdriver, due to "adobe flash player" I am not able to execute flow.

Can someone help me on this?

I have attached Screenshot for reference too:

[image]

Comment: you must have adobe flash player already installed...

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.